# Specs of my Rails app fail randomly because of wrong default locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rails-i18n

From time to time, some specs of my Rails app seem to fail randomly because suddenly English is not the default language anymore, but German:

```
   expected: "Project test customer - Project test name (Audit, Access for all, 2015-06-15).pdf"
        got: "Project test customer - Project test name (Audit, Zugang für alle, 2015-06-15).pdf"
```

As one can see, the part "Access for all" suddenly is "Zugang für alle". I googled for a solution and it seems that [`I18n.locale` is a global object, so when it's changed in a spec, it persists](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/issues/256).

The problem doesn't always occur, but I can reproduce it when specifying a seed like this: `rspec --seed 51012`. So it really seems to be some issue with a spec being executed before (or after) some other spec.

I have a feature spec which tests whether the locale can be changed, like this:

```
it 'offers contents in german' do
  visit root_path(locale: :de)

  expect(page).to have_content 'Willkommen'
end
```

I suspect this could be the problematic spec, and when it's run early, it has impact on other specs.

I hoped that I could solve it by setting the language in the spec back to the default like this:

```
it 'offers contents in german' do
  visit root_path(locale: :de)

  expect(page).to have_content 'Willkommen'

  I18n.locale = :en
end
```

Didn't work, also this one didn't:

```
it 'offers contents in german' do
  visit root_path(locale: :de)

  expect(page).to have_content 'Willkommen'
  visit root_path(locale: :en)
end
```

I'm a bit clueless now. How could I debug the situation, so I definitely find the source of the problem and fix it (or at least work around it)?

**Update**

Using Dave's answer (`rspec --bisect`) I found the problem.

```
# application_controller_spec.rb
describe ApplicationController do
  controller(ApplicationController) do
    def index
      render text: 'Hello World'
    end
  end

  describe 'locale parameter' do
    it 'is set to english when not available in the request' do
      get :index
      expect(I18n.locale).to eq :en
    end

    it 'can be set through the request' do
      get :index, locale: :de
      expect(I18n.locale).to eq :de
    end
  end
end
```

Depending on the order that these specs were run, the locale was set to `:de` or `:en` for following specs.

I fixed it with BoraMa's suggested code snippet:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after(:each) { I18n.locale = :en }
end
```

I'm still a bit astonished that RSpec/Rails don't do this on their own automatically...

Comment: You've not actually shown the failing spec - which may help

Comment: Also - try adding the one you think is causing the issue and the one that is failing to one rspec file, then just run that one file, you can then verify that it is that spec that is causing the issue - rather than running your whole suite

Comment: I'd debug-print the current `I18n.locale` before each test (something like `before(:each) { puts I18n.locale }`, that way, you'll find the offending one. Also, I'd use `after(:each) { I18n.locale = :en }` to reset the locale after each test. Both code snippets should go to `spec/spec_helper.rb` or  `spec/rails_helper.rb`.

Comment: I think you may be papering over the cracks here - what is to say that the default locale couldn't be changed by an equivalent sequence of requests in production?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, Frederick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comment out the spec that you suspect and run `rspec --seed 51012`. If that passes, you know the culprit.

If not, this looks like a job for `rspec --bisect`. Do

```
rspec --seed 51012 --bisect
```

and let RSpec find the minimal set of examples (probably 2) that reproduce the failure. You can then decide what to do about the culprit.

This feature is available in RSpec 3.3 and better in RSpec 3.4. More here: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/bisect

Comment: Wow, did know about `git bisect` but not about `rspec --bisect`! Very good news. I found the problem and updated the question. Thank you!